# If a demonstrative is not modifying a noun, is it called a demonstrative pronoun?

Tags: grammar-identification, demonstrative-pronoun, demonstrative-adjective

I was confused on this since aren't demonstrative adjectives phrases like , "this fast" or "this large". If they are, then demonstrative adjectives not necessarily modifying nouns but adjectives, are certainly called not called a demonstrative pronoun.

Comment: I don't see what this has to with Latin.

Answer (score 6):

A [pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun) is called a pronoun because it stands *in place of* a noun. The preposition *pro* in Latin means “in place of, on behalf of” (well, it is a bit more versatile, but it fits here). So a *proconsul* acts on behalf of a *consul* and a *pronomen* stands in for a *nomen*.

For example:

> Marcus **Claudiae** obviam factus est et **eam** [= Claudiam] salvere iussit.
> *Marcus came across **Claudia** and greeted **her** [= Claudia].*

Here *eam* (her) stands in for the noun *Claudia*. It would be cumbersome and irritating to repeat *Claudia* all the time.

This is called the *substantive* use of demonstrative pronouns, but they can also be used *adjectively* and modify nouns:

> Marcus infitiatus est umquam se **illam puellam** vidisse.
> Marcus denied ever having seen **that girl**.

In that case [they are called](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/demonstrative-pronouns) *adjective pronouns* or *pronomial adjectives*. However, in Latin at least, they are still considered demonstrative pronouns.

Expressions like “this fast” or “that large” are an English peculiarity that has no direct equivalent in Latin.

Comment: It should be noted that a *nomen* includes both substantives (English: "nouns") and adjectives. In English as well, a *noun* could be adjective or substantive (though this usage is now less common). So an adjective is really a kind of nomen/noun.